# How to alter WebStorm smart completion templates

Tags: resharper, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I add a Class into a Typescript Application, WebStorms Smart Code Completion finds the reference and creates an import reference automatically.

This is great, but the format is different to the TSLinter, I was wondering if there is a way of altering the generated code so that it will use single quotes instead of double quotes

[image]

Comment: Not 100% sure.. but try `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript --> Other | Generated Code --> Quote marks`. That's for IDEA-based IDEs. No idea about R#.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @LazyOne, I altered this setting and now single quotes are used. It may be a little bit to much as it will effect all TypeScript string insertions, but I will try this for now.

[image]